# Reversibly disconnect matplotlib's own key press handling

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to temporarily and reversibly disconnect matplotlib's own key press events, i.e. the keyboard shortcuts ("s" -> save, "q" -> quit, etc).

This used to be the way to do this:

```py
fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(fig.canvas.manager.key_press_handler_id)
# Do stuff
fig.canvas.manager.key_press_handler_id \
    = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', fig.canvas.manager.key_press)
```

However, the method `fig.manager.key_press` seems to no longer exist in recent matplotlib versions. How do I temporarily disable matplotlib's event handling now?

Answer (score 0):

As per @anntzer's answer [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26713), one can connect to `backend_bases.key_press_handler` instead.
Thus a monkey patch to restore the previous behavior would look like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import backend_bases

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# monkey patch
fig.canvas.manager.key_press = backend_bases.key_press_handler

# disconnect
fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(fig.canvas.manager.key_press_handler_id)

# do stuff
# [...]

# reconnect
fig.canvas.manager.key_press_handler_id \
    = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', fig.canvas.manager.key_press)
```